# Android: OpenGraph Stories sharing in Facebook with SDK 4.0

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I am trying to implement achievements for sharing to facebook when the player unlocks a badge. Have made an object using the object browser in facebook developer console. I made Action-types and object-types and made a custom story. Now i am stuck trying to share the story to facebook. The documentation given by facebook is inadequate. Even the sample code given by facebook uses v3.x

Sample code given by facebook is given below. Couldnt find any good documentation.

**Code for Object**

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
Request request = new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    "me/objects/enguru_app:badge",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST
);
Response response = request.executeAndWait();
// handle the response
```

**Code for Action**

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("badge", "http://samples.ogp.me/1114467558579559");
Request request = new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    "me/enguru_app:unlocked",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST
);
Response response = request.executeAndWait();
// handle the response
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At Last figured out my own issue.

Here is the solution:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "enguru_app:badge")
            .putString("og:title", "Unlocked Newbie Badge")
            .putString("og:url","xxxx")
            .putString("og:image","xxx")
            .putString("game:points", "10")
            .putString("fb:app_id", "xxx")
            .putString("og:description",
                    "We are rocking. Come and Play with us").build();
    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("enguru_app:unlocked")
            .putObject("badge", object).build();
    // Create the content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("badge").setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(Profile.this, content);
```

I hope this will help someone who is going through the same issue.

Comment: How to do this without the ShareDialog?

Comment: What are other types used other than "badge" with setPreviewPropertyName(...)?

Comment: It looks like setPreviewPropertyName() is for you to specify the key you used for ShareOpenGraphAction.putObject(). An action can have multiple objects set on it so it appears this lets you identify the primary one to be used in the post.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

See this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android Specifically ShareOpenGraphObject and ShareOpenGraphAction.

Also you can debug through Scrumptious: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/SelectionFragment.java#L365

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to share without using `ShareDialog`:

```
ShareApi shareApi = new ShareApi(content);
shareApi.share(new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
});
```

Also you probably want to check `shareApi.canShare()`